get sum of sales per month
Trying to write a query to get the total number of sales per month.
So I can currently write this query to return the month and year:
SELECT 
  DISTINCT(MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%m/%d/%Y'))) AS 'Month'
  ,YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%m/%d/%Y')) AS 'Year'
  ,`total` 
FROM `supermarket_sales`

And I can return the below:

So what I want to do now is get the total for each month.
Using an answer found here:  Total sales per month
And this is my attempt to mimic the accepted answer on the link above:
SELECT 
  DISTINCT(MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%m/%d/%Y'))) AS 'Month',
  YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%m/%d/%Y')) AS 'Year',
  SUM(`total`) AS 'TotalSales'
FROM `supermarket_sales`
GROUP BY YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%m/%d/%Y')), MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%m/%d/%Y'))
ORDER BY YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%m/%d/%Y')), MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%m/%d/%Y'))

But I am getting the below error:

How can I make this work?

Remember that MONTH returns alphabetics that aren't going to sort the way you expect.  I would do the GROUP BY and ORDER BY on the date column first, and then do an outer select to format the date the way you want.

There is no DISTINCT function; what are you trying to do with that?  It is being interpreted as SELECT DISTINCT ...fieldlist but that isn't useful here

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. and Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question are both relevant here.

I think you want GROUP BY LAST_DAY(day) and then SELECT LAST_DAY(day), SUM(total) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day

@Charlieface - I want to get the total for the whole month.

And why won't that work? DId you try it? It's just a better version of GROUP BY YEAR(day), MONTH(day) Putting it another way: if you want the answer from the other link why don't you use it? Your existing solution is obviously wrong, as others have noted. It has an unnecessary DISTINCT and uses STR_TO_DATE and MONTHNAME for some strange reason.

@Charlieface - Using LAST_DAY(date) in my SELECT returns NULL records.  STR_TO_DATE is being used because the data in date are strings and needed to be converted.  MONTHNAME allowed me to grab the month, and I used DISTINCT to get the distinct months.

Ah well that's mistake #1, not storing in the right data type. DISTINCT is the wrong thing, as we keep telling you. And I can't tell why you are getting that result if you don't show some sample data. Please show sample data (like CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements)

Once you use aliases for column in SELECT statement you can refer to same later in the query.
i have tried to create simple table with default date format. It is working fine for me.
creating table:
create table supermarket_sales(date date, total float);

inserting values:
insert into supermarket_sales values
('2019-01-01', 548.971),
('2019-03-01', 80.22),
('2019-03-01', 340.526),
('2019-01-01', 489.048),
('2019-02-01', 634.378),
('2019-03-01', 627.617),
('2019-02-01', 433.692),
('2019-02-01', 772.38),
('2019-01-01', 76.146),
('2019-02-01', 172.746),
('2019-02-01', 60.816);

selecting records as you showed in first query.
select monthname(date) as month, year(date), total as year 
from supermarket_sales;

output of query1
Adding group by and order by:
select distinct(monthname(date)) as month, year(date) as year, sum(total) as year 
from supermarket_sales
group by year,month;

output of query2

This is what worked for me.  Thank you for your help.

Distinct and Group By in the same sql doesn't make sense. Since you want the Sum() aggregation  by year and month - use Group By and lose Distinct...
You should adjust your code like here:
WITH     --  S a m p l e     D a t a :
  supermarket_sales (DATE_STR, VAL) AS
    ( Select '01/17/2019', 548.971 Union All 
      Select '03/15/2019', 80.22 Union All 
      Select '03/19/2019', 340.526 Union All 
      Select '01/24/2019', 489.048 Union All 
      Select '02/21/2019', 634.378 Union All 
      Select '03/07/2019', 627.617 Union All 
      Select '02/21/2019', 433.692 Union All 
      Select '02/21/2019', 772.38 Union All 
      Select '01/26/2019', 76.146 Union All 
      Select '02/27/2019', 172.746 Union All 
      Select '02/28/2019', 60.816 
    ) 

--     S Q L :
SELECT   MonthName( Str_To_Date( DATE_STR, '%m/%d/%Y' ) ) AS month, 
         Year( Str_To_Date( DATE_STR, '%m/%d/%Y' ) ) AS year,
         Sum(VAL) as total
FROM     supermarket_sales
GROUP BY year, month

/*
month       year         total
----------  ----   -----------
January     2019      1114.165
March       2019      1048.363
February    2019      2074.012   */

See the fiddle here.

I do appreciate your help, however the answer from @ChiragPatel was what I was looking for.  Thank you.
